# Как опенсорсеры раздают ip адреса?

Tags: сервер, ip, vps, dhcp

возник следующий вопрос. Есть фирма опенсоурсинг у которой есть 3 серверных компа, они сдают в аренду под хостинг или типа VPS или сервер целиком. Так вот, например мы арендовали у них VPS под свои веб-сервисы php-api, у нас естесственно есть внешний выделенный нам ip от них. Вопрос, откуда они взяли этот ip адрес внешний, они просто купили белый-статичный ip у провайдеров интернета или как?

Comment: +Вопрос, нормальный ли вариант приобрести мощный ПК на i7 2600 например,платить в месяц по 300 руб. интернет провайдеру за статичный ip, и держать там вебсервисы которые должны быть всегда в работе,но не критично если не дай бог свет отключат в офисе.???

Comment: Как бы да, либо взяли у провайдера блок ip, либо сразу взяли подсеть адресов у ближайшего LIR'а, других путей получения адресов не существует. И да, свой сервер на своем интернете вполне нормальное решение. Вообще предполагается, что в нормальном дата-центре кроме того, что электричество зарезервировано, но и интернет зарезервирован. Так что считайте риски пропадания не только света, но и интернета

Comment: альтернативой будет использовать ddns и обращаться к удаленному серверу не по ip-адресу, а по имени - такой функционал присутствует во многих домашних роутерах. Хотя как по мне то использовать ip проще, если такая возможность есть.